# LDAP user to reset their own password, without older password

Tags: openldap

I have the requirement that the ldap user has to change password for himself, without having the older password. As this is for the forgot password feature.

```
public static JsonObject updatePassword(String username, String newPassword, String dnTemplate) {
JsonObject response=new JsonObject();
    String dn = "uid=" + username + "," + dnTemplate;
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];

    mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE,
      new BasicAttribute("userPassword", hashMD5Password(newPassword)));

    try {
      ldapContext.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
      ldapContext.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      
    }
    return response;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean isldapContext=LDAPUtils.initilaizeLDAP("ldap://ip:389","","","");
    System.out.println("isldapContext:"+isldapContext);
    JsonObject res=LDAPUtils.updatePassword("username","password","ou=People,dc=xxx,dc=xxx");
    System.out.println(res);

  }
```

When the above code is executed, m getting the below error:

```
isldapContext:true
javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - modifications require authentication]; remaining name 'uid=111,ou=People,dc=xxx,dc=xxx'
```

Comment: So I could specify someone else's account that I know the username of, and reset the password?

Comment: No. Only that particular user has to do.

Comment: I wanted to know, how forgot password functionality is achieved in OpenLDAP

Comment: My point is that you can't have an unauthenticated password reset without knowing the old password. (Otherwise, you could just enter a username and reset the password for any account!)